# Add D3.js v4 graph within a NgbAccordion in ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, d3.js, ng-bootstrap

I am using Angular (TypeScript) along with `d3.js v4` (version 4.13) and ng-bootstrap.

#### d3-component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg">
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion"
    activeIds="ngb-panel-0, ngb-panel-1" id="accordion">
  <ngb-panel title="State Tracking View">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      <div id="svg1">
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
  <ngb-panel title="Schedule Tracking View">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      <div id="svg2"></div>
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-panel>
  </ngb-accordion>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want add some `svg` within the two `div` components within the `ng-template`.

I just picked up a code from Mike Bostock and am trying to display it within one of the panels of the accordion

#### d3-component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('d3 version ', d3['version']);
    this.loadPiGraph();
  }

  loadPiGraph() { // loading the Extending Arcs graph from Bostock

    var data = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89];

    var width = 960, // some random values for now!
        height = 500;

    var outerRadius = height / 2 - 20,
        innerRadius = outerRadius / 3,
        cornerRadius = 10;

    var pie = d3.pie()
        .padAngle(.02);

    var arc = d3.arc()
        .padRadius(outerRadius)
        .innerRadius(innerRadius);
    /*
       HOW DO I SELECT THE DIVS AND ADD THE GRAPH IN IT?
    */
    var svg = d3.select('ngb-accordion')
    .select('#svg1').append('svg')
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(pie(data))
      .enter().append("path")
        .each(function(d) { d.outerRadius = outerRadius - 20; })
        .attr("d", arc)
        .on("mouseover",() => {
          arcTween(outerRadius, 0);
          AddNode();
        } )
        .on("mouseout", arcTween(outerRadius - 20, 150));

    function arcTween(outerRadius, delay) {
      return function() {
        d3.select(this).transition().delay(delay).attrTween("d", function(d) {
          var i = d3.interpolate(d.outerRadius, outerRadius);
          return function(t) { d.outerRadius = i(t); return arc(d); };
        });
      };
    }

    function AddNode() {
      d3.select('#svg2').append('circle')
      .attr('cx', 30)
      .attr('cy', 40)
      .attr('r', 24)
      .style('fill', 'blue')
      .transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .attr('cx', 340);
    }
  }
```

### Observations

I practically does nothing. I used the browser inspector for the same but there is no `<svg>` tag inserted proving that the `d3.select()` isn't programmed appropriately by me.

However If I do `d3.select('body')` it will add the graph at the bottom of the accordion.

I am not sure how to go about with the selection of the panels in the accordion

Comment: Did you try `d3.select("#accordian")`?  Use the id of the element instead of the element itself?

Comment: yup! I tried it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the answer:

the `ngb-panel-0` which are default `activeIds` for all the panels created the trick for me.

As suggested by @pmkro in the comment i used the `id` of the accordion and then used the `id` of the panel as mentioned above to get the rendering

### Code Snippet

```
var svg = d3.select('#accordion')
        .select('#ngb-panel-0') // this gets the selection
        .append('svg')
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```

## Result

[image: result]